# MongoServerError: bad auth :Authentication Failed

Tags: mongodb

[Geeting This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EihJv.jpg)

```
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.agq2x.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Typically the error is that you did not specify the authentication source, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470